# Rapidly changing Configuration/Status File? JAVA

Tags: java, file-io

I need some way to store a configuration/status file that needs to be changed rapidly. The status of each key value pair (key-value) is stored in that file. The status needs to be changed rather too rapidly as per the status of a communication (Digital multimedia broadcasting) hardware.

What is the best way to go about creating such a file? ini? XML? Any off the shelf filewriter in Java? I can't use databases.

Comment: Input from DSP programmers would be helpful.

Comment: The hardware (currently emulator ) is not standarized and I'm not sure how many or what kinds of products will be using it. In any case I am quite sure the hardware won't allow SQLlite installation:)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need random access to update parts of the file frequently without re-writing the entire file. Design binary file format and use RandomAccessFile API to read/write it. You are going to want to use fixed number of bytes for key and for value, such that you can index into the middle of the file and update the value without having to re-write all of the following records. Basically, you would be re-implementing how a database stores a table.

Another alternative is to only store a single key-value pair per file such that the cost of re-writing the file is minor. Maybe you can think of a way to use file name as the key and only store value in the file content.

I'd be inclined to try the second option unless you are dealing with more than a few thousand records.

Comment: I would say yours could be the best solution so far. Binary hmm.Any off the shelf stuff would be great.

Comment: For an off the shelf solution, look at a relational database or one of the "NoSQL" storage systems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Comment: Note that there are 100% java relational databases and NoSQL systems. If you hardware supports JavaSE, you should be able to run one of those packages.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution would be to put the "configuration" information into a `Properties` object, and then use `Properties.store(...)` or  `Properties.storeToXML(...)` to save to a file output stream or writer.

You also need to do something to ensure that whatever is reading the file will see a consistent snapshot.  For instance, you could write to a new file each time and do a delete / rename dance to replace the the old with the new.

But if the update rate for the file is too high, you are going to create a lot of disc traffic, and you are bound slow down your application.  This is going to apply (eventually) no matter what file format / API you use.  So, you may want to consider not writing to a file at all.

Comment: Thanks I can use this suggestion for the config file (and perhpas use Konstantin's suggestion for reading machine's data )

Answer (score 0):

At some point, configuration that changes too rapidly becomes "program state" and not configuration.  If it is changing so rapidly, why do you have confidence that you can meaningfully write it to, and then read it from, a filesystem?

Say more about what the status is an who the consumer of the data is...

Comment: Actually I should be saying I need to keep track of the states and configs separately. You asked for details so I'll try to say what I'm doing. I am working on a DMB repeater, and I'm making both the protocol and DMB controller via a GUI.  The DMB controller can send control information from one or multiple fast changing sources but it is not as fast as the data it reads. The DMB GUI also has to read the data about the status of the repeater, including fast changing SNR and voltage ups+downs so that it can change the interface (say the GUI images turn from green to red on alarms).